# delete heap after returning pointer

Tags: c++

I have a function as below

```
int* readFile(string InputPath)
{
    int *myvar = new int[10]; //The file has 10 lines (Using heap)

    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(InputPath.c_str(), ios::in);

    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error reading the input file ";
        cout << InputPath << ".";
        exit(0);
    }
    string fileLine;

    while (getline(inFile, fileLine))
    {
       myvar[i]=toint(fileLine); //will be converted to int!
    }
    ;
    inFile.close();



    return myvar;
}:
```

How can I free the heap (myvar)?
In general, what is the best method to return such array?

Comment: Best method - use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: You are passing the responisibilty on to the caller of the function. It's better to return a smart pointer (that manages the ownership), or use a container.

Comment: @BoPersson: I concur, but I think that's the least of his concerns given that he does an `exit(0)` if the given file can't be opened. :-]

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` might be what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It clearly becomes the responsibility of the caller, to call `delete[]` on it. Note that this means the caller has to know that the returned pointer is allocated with `new[]`, which isn't exactly optimal.

You should return a `std::vector<int>` instead, which makes it all so much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

**How can I free the heap (myvar)?**

The int* you return; don't change it, don't lose it, and when you're done with the memory,

```
delete [] theReturnedPointer;
```

Unless you've got a really good reason for making it an array, you could save yourself the bother of memory management and just use a vector.

**best method**

The best method is to return a vector:

```
vector<int> readFile(const string& InputPath)
{
    ifstream inFile(InputPath); // or inputPath.c_str() for old compilers
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Error reading the input file " << InputPath << ".";
        exit(0); // thow would be better! Or at least return an empty vector.
    }

    vector<int> myvar;
    for(int n; inFile >> n && myvar.size() < 10; )
    {
       myvar.push_back(n);
    }
    return myvar;
}
```

But if you really really want to use `new[]`, then at least return the self-managing pointer, `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`. Never let a raw pointer escape a function, not in C++.

Comment: I think your `for` loop is quite creative, I had to read that twice to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

The caller must `delete[]` the value returned from the function. The code as it stands provides no protection for writing beyond the end of the array:

```
while (getline(inFile, fileLine))
{
    myvar[i]=toint(fileLine); //will be converted to int!
}
```

However, as this is C++ use a [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead and read `int`s directly from the input stream instead of reading them as strings and performing the conversion. The `std::vector<int>` will handle memory management for you:

```
std::vector<int> myvar;

int i;
while (inFile >> i) myvar.push_back(i);
```

Return the `std::vector<int>` from the function. The caller can know exactly how many `int`s are in the return value (which it cannot if you return an array unless you include a sentinel value to indicate the end) and does not need to explicitly delete it.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some code which will call delete on this pointer.

I think, better way to do this is to get a pointer as argument.
Doing it that way would force someone using this function to initialize array, so he would know, he has to delete it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The convention in  C++ is to not return allocated memory. Instead, the function prototype should look like

```
size_t readFile(string InputPath,int* array,size_t n_elements);
```

The function returns the number of elements it actually placed in array. The caller will allocate and free memory using appropriate method, not nessecary new/delete[] but also malloc/free or lower level system functions such as VirtualAlloc.