# Who should free Memory?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delete heap after returning pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490284/delete-heap-after-returning-pointer)

I have a class with a member function:

```
char* toChar();
```

The member function allocates memory and return a pointer to that memory ...

lets say I would use it like this:

```
int main() {
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    char* str = mc.toChar();

    return 0; 
}
```

where should I free the memory? In the Destructor of the class or in the program like this:

```
int main() {
    MyClass * mc = new MyClass();
    char* str = mc.toChar();
    // tostuff with str
    delete mc;
    delete[] str; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Up to you to decide and document. But better use a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Comment: Who _owns_ that memory? What is its _lifetime_, with respect to the `MyClass` instance that created it? How is it actually _used_?

Comment: Naked pointers are *evil*. You just discovered the reason why. Now start believing that you shouldn't use them.

Comment: @Kerrek: const references are "evil" for precisely the same reason, some numpty^Hnovice might see a const reference and not know who owns any resources associated with the referand. Now tell me you believe you shouldn't use const references :-p

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't follow... if you see a const reference, you don't generally care about who owns it. You just assume that it's not you.

Comment: @Kerrek: unless the documentation says otherwise. The same is true of raw pointers unless the documentation says otherwise. Novices often confuse raw pointers with ownership and get in a muddle. *Non-novices also often confuse raw pointers with ownership*, and think that all pointers must come with ownership and hence must be smart pointers instead. They're both wrong.

Comment: @SteveJessop: But references are more or less self-documenting. Raw pointers *never* are. One very useful guideline is to write code, not documentation, as long as the code is readable and locally understandable. That's entirely possible with references.

Comment: @Kerrk: references are not inherently self-documenting. You're just less confused about them. Imagine that everybody uses smart pointers correctly, then a raw pointer has *exactly* the same ownership semantics as a reference (i.e., none), and is *exactly* as self-documenting. The only problem is that you're anticipating the kind of general confusion about ownership that it's much better to educate away. If you don't let people into your code base who try to use a raw pointer for ownership, then you don't have to (wrongly) worry that a raw pointer implies ownership.

Comment: The reason this is good is because it allows you (for example) to use raw pointers to describe a graph-like structure amongst a set of objects you own (e.g. the elements of a `set` or `deque`), without them all having to share ownership in each other. It also allows you to do that style rule about passing a pointer for out-params in preference to a non-const reference. Personally I can live without that rule, but it's nice to know that if I were to code by it, I wouldn't have to put *everything* into a `shared_ptr` (from which it can never be released) just to pass it as an out-param.

Comment: Here's an example of raw pointers being self-documenting, btw. I'm not talking about anything particularly unusual: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8376611/13005. I suppose you could invent a `non_owning_ptr` for the purpose, which is purely a wrapper for a raw pointer. If you've done that then I apologise, your code is more clearly self-documenting than mine. `std::ref` can maybe serve the purpose too, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be reusable (that is, you can call it multiple times and it may return different values, maybe because the class has changed), then you should free it in the main. Otherwise it's up to you.

But in general you should NOT use plain strings. You should change it to use `std::string` and then return that by value.

Answer (score 1):

The member function should return an object that manages the memory.  Typically that would be `std::unique_ptr`, but for `char` data `std::string` may be more appropriate:

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    std::string toChar();
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc;
    std::string str = mc.toChar();
}
```

Note that by also making `mc` a managed object (here it is managed directly on the stack; `unique_ptr` would also work but would be largely unnecessary) there is no need for `delete` to appear anywhere in your code.  In general, unless you are writing your own containers, `delete` should not appear in your code.

Comment: Even if you *are* writing your own containers, `delete` still should not appear in your code. Make them configurable with a memory allocator, like standard containers are, then use `destroy` and `deallocate` on the allocator :-)

Comment: why not to use new/delete? Just using brain while programming should solve most issues ... all smart_pointers use also delete to free the memory.

Comment: @anhadikal actually, as Steve Jessop points out, smart pointers use the allocator to release memory. Using raw pointers will result in memory leaks for unexpected code paths e.g. exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The question is who is the "owner" of that piece of memory pointed by str. As mc returns a char* instead of a const char*, it allows the client (str) to modify the value of the string, so I would say str should also consequently take care of freeing the memory. What would happen if mc frees the memory but str still want to access it? The process will be terminated.